How to get the same energy spectrum in spin formalism and Fermion formalism connected by Jordan-Wigner transformation?
I am now working on the kicked Ising model mentioned in Google's paper. I want to solve the energy spectrum of kicked Ising model in both spin formalism and Fermion formalism. The two are connected by Jordan-Wigner transformation(JWT) and their energy spectrum should be the same. But my calculations give different results. I want to know where is wrong.
Below are details

Kicked Ising model is actually a Floquet system, having only evolution operator in the form:
$$ U_F = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2} J \sum_{i}Z_iZ_{i+1}}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}g\sum_{i}X_i} $$
where $Z_i$ and $X_i$ represent the Pauli oprators of qubit $i$. Such a system does not really have an eigenenergy, none the less an energy spectrum. But there is a Hamiltonian $H_F$ playing the role of effective 'static' Hamiltonian: $U_F = e^{-iH_F}$(Suppose time $T=1$). This system is known to have a Majorana $0$ mode and $\pi$ mode in Fermion formalism(see this paper). So the energy spectrum of $H_F$ should have bond states at $0$ and $\pm\pi$.
In Google's paper, the experiments are in spin formalism but they discussed their result in Fermion formalism and these two are connected by JWT. As far as I know, JWT won't change the energy spectrum. So I expect to see bond states of $0$ and $\pm\pi$ energy in the energy spectrum of both formalism. This is how I calculate the energy spectrum and the result.
Spin formalism

write down $U_F$. Take 2 qubits for example:
$$ U_F = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}JZ_1Z_2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}g(X_1+X_2)} = \exp\left[ -i \frac{\pi}{2}J
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right]\exp \left[ -i\frac{\pi}{2}g
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\right]  $$

Take the logarithm of $U_F$ to get effective Hamiltonian: $H_F=i\log(U_F)$.

Diagonalise $H_F$ to get the energy spectrum.

Change the value of $g$ and get a series of energy spectrum.


The result I get is obivously wrong! No bond states can be seen and even not a state lies at $0$ energy!

Fermion formalism

Change the operator into Fermion formalism using JWT. The transformation I take is the same as Google's paper(mentioned in the sumpplyment material):
$$ \sigma_j^- = \Pi_{i=1}^{j-1}e^{i\pi c_i^{\dagger}c_i}c_j^\dagger, \ \ \  X_j=1-2c_j^\dagger c_j =e^{i\pi c_j^\dagger c_j} $$
And the resulting $U_F$ is:
$$ U_F = \Pi \exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2}J(c_j^\dagger+c_j)(c_{j+1}-c_{j+1}^\dagger) \right) \Pi \exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2}g(c_jc_j^\dagger-c_j^\dagger c_j) \right)$$

There are superconducting terms in $U_F$, so use particle-hole symmetry to write $U_F$ in a symmetry way. The transformation is:
$$ c_j^\dagger c_m = 1/2(c_j^\dagger c_m - c_m c_j^\dagger +\delta_{jm}) $$
$$ c_jc_m^\dagger = 1/2(c_jc_m^\dagger - c_m^\dagger c_j + \delta_{jm}) $$
$$ c_jc_m = 1/2(c_jc_m-c_mc_j) $$
$$ c_j^\dagger c_m^\dagger = 1/2(c_j^\dagger c_m^\dagger - c_m^\dagger c_j^\dagger) $$

Write $c_j, c_j^\dagger$ in vector forms:
$$ c_j=[e_j, e_0] , \ \ \ c_j^\dagger=[e_0, e_j]$$
where $e_j = [0, 0, ..., 0,1, 0, ...]$(The ith element is 1 and else are all 0) and $e_0 = [0,0, ..., 0]$. And write $U_F$ in the basis of $c_j, c_j^\dagger$ so that it becomes a $2N\times 2N$ matrix.

Take logarithm of $U_F$ to get effective Hamiltonian $H_F$.

Diagonalise $H_F$ and get the eigenenergies.

Change the value of $g$ to get an energy spectrum.


The result I get by this method is correct. There are the expected $0$ and $\pi$ mode and the critical point is also right. By the way, if I don't use the particle-hole symmetry and directly choose $2^n$ basis to calculate the energy spectrum, I get the same 'wrong' result as in spin formalism(I also don't know why).
$0$ and $\pi$ modes are clear." />

I think the problem is that my method to calculate energy spectrum in spin formalism is wrong. But I've searched many papers and textbooks and I cann't figure out how to do it correctly. Maybe someone can give any suggestions?
